# Mulesoft - capture http status

Tags: mulesoft

Calling a soap web service and checking the web service response's http status with a groovy script.
In Mule 3, groovy script is...

```
def httpStatus = message.getInboundProperty('http.status')
if (httpStatus == '400') {
     throw new Exception('Bad Request');
 }
return payload;
```

What is the equivalent in Mule 4?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`#[attributes.statusCode]` is the equivalent expression to Mule 3 #[inboundProperties.’http.status] (https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-request-ref#map-between-http-responses-and-mule-messages). I don't remember of the top of my head if attributes map to Groovy scripts in Mule 4, you will need to try it.

I recommend to avoid using Groovy or other script language for error handling and use Mule built-in error handling instead.